# jQuery On() eventHandler parameter as a function name with parameter

Tags: jquery

From jQuery website:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

How can i write a correct code to pass a parameter from ON method to the event handler Function...

**I want a code like this:**

```
myfunc =function(obj){
$(this).after("<p>Another paragraph! "+obj+"</p>");
}

var count = 0;
$("body").on("click", "p",myfunc(++count) );
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you intend to increment the count on every click:

```
var count = 0;
$("body").on("click", "p",function(){
    $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph! " + (++count) + "</p>");
});
```

**Edit**, if you want your function to be separate and don't want to change it, you can do this:

```
myfunc = function(obj){
    $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph! "+obj+"</p>");
}

var count = 0;
$("body").on("click", "p",function(){
    myfunc.call(this, ++count);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bwk3W/

Comment: That doesn't equal to the code he tried, your code doesn't save the value of `count`, it can change before the event will fire.

Comment: @gdoron that's what the 2nd bit in the answer is about.  Though lookign at it again, I think both of our answers are wrong.  I believe he wants to increment the count on every click, not cache the value.

Comment: +1, well it seams that he wants your answer, I'll give my answer live because It better answer the question text...

Comment: @JamesMontagne, i know your answe is correct, but i want an answer like gdoron answer

Comment: @RAM Updated my answer.  If this isn't what you want either then you'll need to explain your question better.

Comment: The only problem is that `count` variable is being too much global.

Comment: @JamesMontagne, both your answers (you and gdoron) are nice and useful

Answer (score 4):

```
myfunc =function(event){
    $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph! "+event.data+"</p>");
}

$("body").on("click", "p", ++count, myfunc);
```

The data you send is being inserted to the event object:

> **data**
>
> Data to be passed to the handler in `event.data` when an event is triggered.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject)

Comment: @Nelson, it works just fine, this is how you pass values, if you want the value to change, you will need to use different methods then the OP asked.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand the question right then.. sorry for the noise.

Comment: it is ok, but i want to increment the count every time the P is clicked, not cache the value

Comment: @Ram, then use James's answer.

Comment: i want define the function out of ON() method and set it as the eventHandler

Comment: @RAM, that's funny... I would use his code, making my code adapting changes to the parameters is way to complicated.

Comment: i have tried @JamesMontagne answer befor writing this question on stackoverflow. but i want seperate function :D

Comment: @RAM, I'm in a bit hurry, please ping me on sunday, I'll try to answer more in-depth then. anyway, I suggest using James answer, it's robust and easy to read & maintain.